# Post request - sent data in json format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a study project.
Have a simple form with input and button. Need to save an input value into JSON file. 
HTML

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="emailForm">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email for newsletter">
    <button type="submit" id="subscribe" value=""><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

JS to convert data into JSON format

```
$('#subscribe').on('click', function (event) {
        // prevent from reloading the page
        event.preventDefault();
        // checking validity of input
        if (ValidateEmail()) {
            var formData = $("#emailForm").serializeArray();
            $.each(formData, function () {
                if (jsonData[this.name]) {
                    if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                        jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
                    }
                    jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }

                jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

            });

            console.log(jsonData);


            $.ajax({
                url: "app.js",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: jsonData

            }); 
            alert('Email saved!');
            return jsonData;

        } else {
            console.log('email not saved');
        }
    });
```

app.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('email.json', (err, data) => {  
    if (err) throw err;
    let email = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('original' + email);
});
fs.writeFileSync('email.json', jsonData);  
console.log('done');
```

the problem is with accessing file app.js - first, it's blocked by chrome

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///D:/HTML/Try%20it/acad/master/app.js' from origin 'null' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Cross-origin requests are only supported
>   for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Tried to run a local server with node.js and received Error 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: since app.js uses `fs`, you are required to run it through node. You'll have to send the POST request to that web server as well. Your hard disk has no idea what a POST request is or how it should handle HTTP connections, so you can't run these kind of scripts locally.

Comment: you need a running server. It is trying to access the file localy. in other words, visit the page through http://localhost, not doubleclicking it

Comment: have installed node http-server - http://localhost:8080/ and same - the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js is just a script, that start to read a file, write one by blocking the thread, print 'done' and shutdown. No HTTP server, no request handling...

What you need first is to set up a HTTP server, this can be done with the native `http` node.js module, or with other modules (like `express`), so that you listen for events, and trigger code when a the server is called.

Also, the `http-server` is made to quickly render some files, trying to `POST` to a text file obviously do nothing, and if you were to `GET` it, you would simply get you text file, which do you no good.

So depending on what are your homework constraint, you need to either check [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html), or [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) documentation, set up a valid HTTP server, and on that call, correctly write to your file.

(Tips: Do not use `...Sync` function in node.js, unless you really do know what you are doing, and check what "asynchronous" functions are, you will need it)